# Printing an InfoPath view in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, infopath

I've got a button in the infoPath form called btnPrint that I link through formcode.cs, how can I make the button print the current view using the default printer settings?

I found that you can use xmlform.print() or this.print but it states that there is no definition for it.

Comment: There is probably a way to do this, but why not just use the built-in InfoPath print buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode
("FullXPath", this.NamespaceManager).Value) <= 35)
{
    this.Print();
}
```